# Webscraping Source Page with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There's classwork we do at school on a website called Focus On Sound. I've found that the answers for the questions are visible when you view the source page.
Repl with Example: https://repl.it/@KhalilNourElDin/SleepyPessimisticTheories?folderId=

On line 152 the variable `answer_text` has the answers stored for each question. I want to extract all the answers from a given link and print them to the console.

I've looked at beautiful soup online but it looks quite complicated.

Comment: a login is needed to see your link

Comment: @madik_atma Fixed it!

Comment: Iterate over the results of `soup.findAll("question")` and use `item["answer_text"]` to fetch answer_text.